# Wordpress shortcode to display post date +1 day

Tags: php, wordpress, function, date

I'm trying to create a shortcode that will display the post date +1 day.  Example: if the post was published on the 3rd I want a shortcode that will display 4th.  I've tried the following but not getting the results I want.

```
// [nextday]  
function displaydate_next(){  
    return the_time('jS', strtotime('+1 day')); 
}  
add_shortcode('nextday', 'displaydate_next'); 
// end nextday date
```

Comment: What results is it giving you? Edit: you'll have to pass the post's date as the second parameter to `strtotime()`, otherwise you'll always get *tomorrow*'s date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you also need to get the month and year so it can calculate the next day. The below is what you need:

```
// [nextday]  
function displaydate_next(){  

$time = get_the_time('jS F, Y');
$date = strtotime(date("jS F, Y", strtotime($time)) . " +1 day");
return date('jS', $date); 

}  
add_shortcode('nextday', 'displaydate_next'); 
// end nextday date
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WP Date and Time Shortcode](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-date-and-time-shortcode/) for the purpose. Just add `days="+1"` as an attribute.

For example: `[wp-dt item="custom" format="jS" days="+1"]`.